# Laravel, подтверждение почты

Tags: php, laravel

Выполняю стандартный набор действий для авторизации и подтверждения почты:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan ui:auth
```

Далее в маршруты добавляю:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('verified');
```

Указал настройки smtp, проверял, почта отправляется.

Начинаю выполнять регистрацию и у меня сразу входит в систему, без какого либо перехода на страницу для подтверждения, без ошибок и без отправки сообщения на почту. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему-то к модели User не был добавлен `implements MustVerifyEmail`, вопрос исчерпан.